# Windows Phone Open .rails web page

Tags: c#, webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, castle-monorail

i'm developing a WP 8.1 app in C#, in one page i have to open a ".rail" web page (in webview) but every time i'll open that page the phone ask me to install an app from the store to satisfy the request.

There's any way to prevent this behavior or there's something that i've misconfigured in webView?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `.rails` extension is not a Ruby on Rails convention. It is often used with MonoRail. Retagged.

Answer (score 0):

The default experience in any browser is that when you navigate to a file extension that it isn't able to open it will see it as a downloadable file. For the phone browsers it often means it will download it and search for a app that is able. As far as I know the webview isn't able to open a .rail directly so it will execute the default experience

**TL;DR;** It will try to download the file and search a matching app since it isn't able to open it himself.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought web browsers only look at the `Content-Type` HTTP header (especially since most modern web pages don't have "extensions"), if the page doesn't come back from the server as `text/html` (or one of the variations) it won't know what to do with it. I'd be looking at the HTTP response from the server, then verifying MonoRail and IIS are configured correctly.

Comment: Tanks for help, i've checked the Content-Type and it's "text/html; charset=utf-8", and the browser open properly the page, but every time ask me to find an app on the store. There no way to prevent this? I know is a system message, but if everything works fine with the webView why i have to use an other app? Thanks again

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to prevent it.